# How to update License Agreement(EULA) in MSI Package (support multiple language) using any external tool?

Tags: installshield, eula

I have created MSI Package using InstallShield@2014 supporting languages
English - United States(1033)
Chinese - Taiwan(1028)
Chinese - China(2052)

Language MST file (1033.mst, 1028.mst & 2052.mst) is embedded with MSI Package.
My requirement is to update MIS Package License Agreement(EULA) for all supporting languages from any external tool & Repackage MSI Package and share to end user.
When end user install MSI Package he/she can see updated License Agreement(EULA) for all supporting languages.
I tried many way to update MIS Package License Agreement(EULA) but unable to find correct way to update License Agreement(EULA).

Please help me to update License Agreement(EULA) in MSI Package using any external tool.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Regards,
Krishna Kumar